# How to customize the color of the jquery slider range?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When using the jquery slider, I would like to change the default color of the selected range from grey to blue.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            var slider = $('.slider').slider({
                range: "min",
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                change: function (e, ui) {
                    //                    $("#img1").fadeOut();
                    //                    alert("done");
                },
                slide: function (e, ui) {
                    var point = ui.value;
                    $("#selected_value").html(point);
                    var width = 100 - point;
                   $("#range").css({ "width": point + "%" });
                }

            });
```

my html:

```
<div>
        Min: <span id="selected_value">0</span><br />

    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="slider"><div id="range"></div></div>
    </div>
```

and my css:

```
#range
{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color:Blue;
}
```

Comment: Is this for just one slider or all your sliders? Did you check the themeroller (if it's for all)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to specify this with CSS:

```
div.ui-slider-range.ui-widget-header {
    background: blue;
}
```

If you only want to target a subset of your sliders, restrict the selector accordingly.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/vrVWT/1/)**.

Answer (score 2):

LOOK AT THIS FOR SOLUTION

```
.ui-widget-header{background-image:none;background-color:#A157A4;}
.ui-widget-content { background: #FFCCCC; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a slider range use this in the slider function to change the UI

```
$("#slider-range .ui-slider-range").css({"background":"#ef2929"});

$("#slider-range .ui-slider-handle").css({"border-color":"#ef2929"});
```