# Change background-color to the right of handle on jQuery UI slider

Tags: jquery, background, slider

How do I change the background-color to the right of the handle on the jQuery UI slider? It must be adaptive to slider movements so the background-color to the left of the handle always is one color and the background-color to the right of the handle always is another color.

Comment: Did you try something? What did you try?

Comment: not sure but there may be a class of `ui-slider-range` that you can style: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436849/how-to-customize-the-color-of-the-jquery-slider-range or http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/EFdYv/3/

Comment: @Pete very cool fiddle Pete! Appreciated, it was very useful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the comments! I solved it by adding (range: 'min',) and then changing the background in .ui-slider-range to the background I want to the left and the slider-background sets the background on the right:

```
$(function() {
$("#slider").slider({
    range: 'min',
    value:100, 
    min:10, 
    max:150, 
    step:10, 

    slide: function( event, ui ) {                  

    }
});
});

.ui-slider-range {
    background: red !important;
}
```

Comment: +1! Never imagined it could be so simple and that [`range` property supported `String` type](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-range)! I was about to ask your question, so thank you for answering yourself :)

Comment: Note that there is a serious side-effect to changing the range from "true" to "min" - the sliders will then be able to cross each other, which is usually not a good thing for most usage cases.